# How can I get session data in my controller after user is logged in

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have extended `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` in my `Spring Boot` `MVC` application. I also created the below method

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/")
        .permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/registration")
        .permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/dashboard")
        .hasAuthority("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
        .usernameParameter("email")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/home")
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
}
```

After the user logs in, I need some information like username, role, email, etc in my `/dashboard` controller. How can I achieve that?

I tried googling but could not find any concrete information about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have few options:

1. You can call the static method `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` (this way you can get the credentials all over you application)
2. If you are in the controller, you can have a `Principle` as a parameter to get the information
3. If you want the authentication token, you can have an `Authentication` as a parameter.

Note that you have to have some kind of mechanism to authenticate the user (openid with active-directory for instance) and make you server work with it.

See http://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security for more information